# How can I write text on an image and not go outside of the border?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a gif that I'm breaking up frame by frame and saving them as images. I wrote text on them using `ImageDraw`, but now I'm running into a problem. The text is going outside of the border. The catch is that I'm grabbing a random gif from the internet using a script, so I can't hardcode either in the size of the font nor the amount text to write. How can I ensure that the text I add to the image stays inside the borders of the image?

**Example of what's happening:**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYXmP.png)

**The section of code that deals with writing on the image:**

```
meme_text = "When your kitten is thinking about tuna but has none"
for i in range(0,max_frame_int + 1):
    writeimg = Image.open("frameinstance" + str(i) + ".png")
    newimg = Image.new("RGB", writeimg.size)
    newimg.paste(writeimg)
    width_image = newimg.size[0]
    height_image = newimg.size[1]
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(newimg)
    # font = ImageFont.truetype(<font-file>, <font-size>)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("impact.ttf", 50)
    # draw.text((x, y),"Sample Text",(r,g,b))
    draw.text((int(0.05*width_image), int(0.7*height_image)),meme_text,(255,255,255),font=font)
    newimg.save("newimg" + str(i) +".png")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is you're not accounting for the size of the text that will be rendered vs. the width of the picture. if you change the `font = ImageFont...` line to the following:

```
for font_size in range(50, 0, -1):
    font = ImageFont.truetype("impact.ttf", font_size)
    if font.getsize(meme_text)[0] <= width_image:
        break
else:
    print 'no fonts fit!'
```

the script will find the largest font size that will fit all of the text.

Comment: I tried this on the sample image you posted and the script found that 10pts was the largest font that could fit the whole text, and indeed wrote it out and it did fit.

Comment: Sublime text editor is giving me an indentation error. I'm new to Python, so I don't understand these weird indentation rules yet.

Comment: @user7389351 if your existing code uses tabs, just change each set of four-space indentations above to 1 tab.

Comment: @jknupp ohhhhhhh that's much simpler than what I've been reading online about changing the Sublime settings and whatnot.